# Straighten-Out 2's Complement

Tags: java, integer, bit-manipulation, twos-complement

If I have a byte[] of length n, containing the 2's complement representation of some n-byte integer, how do I get a byte[] of same length with a "straight" representation of the number? Is this even possible, given how there are more negative than positive integers representable with 2's complements?

By "straight" representation I mean something that will continuously map the integer range to some range of bytes, without jumps, holes, etc.

e.g.

```
for the 1-byte integer -128, the two's complement representation is 1000 0000
for the 1-byte integer   -1, the two's complement representation is 1111 1111
for the 1-byte integer    0, the two's complement representation is 0000 0000
for the 1-byte integer    1, the two's complement representation is 0000 0001
for the 1-byte integer  127, the two's complement representation is 0111 1111
```

What I'm looking for is something to convert above values into something like this:

```
for the 1-byte integer -128, the "straight" representation would be 0000 0000
for the 1-byte integer   -1, the "straight" representation would be 0111 1111
for the 1-byte integer    0, the "straight" representation would be 1000 0000
for the 1-byte integer    1, the "straight" representation would be 1000 0001
for the 1-byte integer  127, the "straight" representation would be 1111 1111
```

Is there any proper name for what I've dubbed "straight" representation here?

I'd prefer Java in the solutions, but any other easily/intuitively understandable language or pseudocode is ok too. (Is there anything special to be wary of in this conversion, since Java doesn't have unsigned bytes?)

Comment: The 2's complement of a positive number is the number, with a high-order zero.  The 2's complement of a negative number is the 1's complement (ie, all ones and zeros flipped) and then add 1.  So the 2's complement of 00000001 is (11111110 + 1) or 11111111.  The high-order bit of a 2's complement number always the sign -- 1 for a negative number, 0 for a positive one.

Comment: Your "straight" representation doesn't make sense (other than to note that it's apparently 2's complement with the sign bit flipped).  The main alternative to 2's complement is 1's complement where the bits are just flipped, but the high-order bit is still the sign bit.

Comment: Mapping the most negative number to 0 and the most positive number to all ones is called "offset binary" or "excess-128" (in this case it's 128 anyway)

Comment: Yep, @harold recognized that what you have is "offset binary", et al.  Converting to that from 2's complement is, as I said, a simple matter of flipping the sign bit when the base is -128.  When the base (zero) is not -128, conversion is a matter of subtracting the base from the source number.

Comment: "Offset binary" might be used, eg, to represent temperatures from -40 to +215.  The -40 would be subtracted from (ie, +40 added to) the source temperature, and the result stored in an unsigned 8-bit variable.